# IONIC2 Apollo Graphql Eror: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'

Tags: ionic2, graphql, apollo-client

im starting develop ionic app using graphql service but im got some problem in nodes modules, how can i solve this?

```
[14:32:44]  typescript: D:/ionic/node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts, line: 17 
            Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.

      L16:      subscribeFieldResolver?: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any>
      L17:  ): AsyncIterator<ExecutionResult>;

[14:32:44]  typescript: D:/ionic/node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts, line: 29 
            Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.

      L28:      fieldResolver?: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any>
      L29:  ): AsyncIterable<any>;
```

this my package.json

```
 {
      "name": "Test",
      "author": "test,
      "homepage": "http://test.com",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
        "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.9",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
        "apollo-angular": "^0.13.0",
        "apollo-client": "^1.9.1",
        "graphql-tag": "^2.4.2",
        "ionic-angular": "^2.1.0",
        "ionic-native": "2.5.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.2.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.7.7"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.4",
        "typescript": "^2.3.4"
      },
      "cordovaPlugins": [
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "cordova-plugin-camera",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version"
      ],
      "cordovaPlatforms": [],
      "description": "TEST"
    }
```

Comment: which library did you install? can you share package.json?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and the discussion in https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions/issues/83 helped. Check it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you installed the type declarations for [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js). The npm link is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql).

Type declaration link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/graphql).

Neither the type declarations nor the library seems to be present in the package.json.

If this is the library you intend to use,you need to install using `--save` option as below:

```
npm install --save graphql
```

And types with `save-dev` option to add to dev dependencies.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/graphql
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer my Indian bro! Saved my 3 days

Answer (score 6):

add **"esnext.asynciterable"** lib to file **tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
     . . .
     "esnext.asynciterable"
     . . .
   ],
. . .
```